# Leaflet for R: markerCluster colors

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there are way to make the marker clusters change color based on the color of the circle markers that are clustered?

I made a map looking at homicides in my city: https://jwier85.github.io/murdermap/murdermapFINAL.html

I used green markers for solved homicides and red markers for unsolved homicides. The marker clusters, however, show as green whenever there are fewer than ten things clustered.

I know you can change based on the count, but is there a way I could make clusters of unsolved homicides red? Also, if I can do it in R that would be preferred.